# What is HandlerLeak?

Tags: android

ADT's lint checker says:

> This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur

What's the meaning of the leak handler?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

from http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks

> ### HandlerLeak
>
> Summary: Ensures that Handler classes do not hold on to a reference to an
>   outer class
>
> Priority: 4 / 10
>   Severity: Warning
>   Category: Performance
>
> In Android, Handler classes should be static or leaks might occur. Messages
>   enqueued on the application thread's MessageQueue also retain their target
>   Handler. If the Handler is an inner class, its outer class will be retained as
>   well. To avoid leaking the outer class, declare the Handler as a static nested
>   class with a WeakReference to its outer class.